# Fourier Transform of a signal using direct integration and properties

Tags: signal-analysis, fourier-transform, continuous-signals, transform, fourier

Am trying to compute the Fourier Transform of a function using the properties of the Fourier Transform once and checking my answer using direct integration. My problem is that am not getting the same for both ways.

[image: This is the problem]

Sorry for not being able to type the equations as I am not familiar on how to do that, It would be great if somebody can tell me how. Your help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: yes, you can see from the transformation in (1) that I made it two parts. That is, I split g(2t-1) into two parts.  First I used the the time shift property for g(t-1), then I used the time scaling property for g(2t). Do you know why using properties for Fourier transform is not matching the direct Integration method? Thanks.

Comment: I should have included u(t), I apologize I already assumed it. And for the properties part I would still get e^(-jw)

Answer (score 5):

Your first solution using the properties of the Fourier transform is correct. Your second solution is wrong, because you forgot to include the unit step function. Your function $g(t)$ should be defined by

$$g(t)=e^{-t}u(t)\tag{1}$$

which gives for $g(2t-1)$

$$g(2t-1)=e^{-(2t-1)}u(2t-1)=e^{-(2t-1)}u\left(t-\frac12\right)\tag{2}$$

Consequently, the Fourier integral is given by

$$\mathcal{F}\{g(2t-1)\}=\int_{\frac12}^{\infty}e^{-(2t-1)}e^{-j\omega t}dt\tag{3}$$

I'm sure you can prove now that the result of $(3)$ equals the result you got from using the properties of the Fourier transform.

Comment: can you complete the solution please because am still not getting the same answer. Am getting (e^(2-jw/2))/(2+jw)

Comment: @Raykh: It's exactly like the integral you already solved, just with $1/2$ as the lower integration limit instead of $0$. So in your last expression before evaluating the limits just replace $t$ by $1/2$ and you got it.

Comment: That is what I exactly did and I ended up with a different answer as I stated in my previous comment.

Comment: @Raykh: There must be a very basic mistake in your calculations. Please show us your steps and we can take a look. Probably while writing things down you'll find the error yourself.